# Configuring a Hudson job to run on both Windows and Linux based OS's

Tags: build, build-process, hudson, build-automation

I'm new to Hudson and am working on setting up a job that will build an HG repository of C++ source on multiple platforms.  (Linux, Solaris, FreeBSD, and Windows)

I've got all the platforms working except Windows and it revolves around the fact that I have the Hudson job executing a Python script via the shell.  (i.e. In the Hudson job configuration under the "Build" section I have "Execute Shell" => "Command" => `python ./build_project.py`)

```
[win32] $ /bin/sh -xe C:\Users\build\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson3063181706777016948.sh
The system cannot find the path specified
FATAL: command execution failed
```

Is there a way, outside of creating another job to run just the Windows build, to have Hudson execute the build_project script as Shell for the Unix type OSes and execute it as a batch file when the target is a Windows slave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use the python plugin: http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Python+Plugin

With this you simply specify the python file that should be executed.

Comment: Thanks.  This is the type of solution I was looking for.  I figured I could install Cygwin and make it work, but this allows me to do what I need without adding additional software as we have Python installed for Mercurial on all our build machines.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend installing Cygwin on your windows boxes so that they can run UNIX shell scripts. That's what we do and it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ant script, build.xml in your workspace that contains:

```
<target name="default">
    <exec executable="python">
        <arg value="./build_project.py"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

Then in Hudson, instead of the "Execute Shell" do a "Invoke Ant" instead. Make the target "default" (no quotes). You'll have to install/point to ant in your Hudson->Manage Hudson->Configure System->Ant section(not in the job, in the main Hudson config) but it should work.